# Bootstrap3: mobile first approach, prevent rules for xs from applying to bigger screen sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I using Bootstrap 3.3 and authoring with mobile first approach. Here is the the css:

```
       .link{
            display: block;
            margin: 7px auto;
            text-align: center;

            /*Tablets+ only*/
            @media(min-width: 768px){
                float: right;
                position: relative;
                top: 10px;  }
```

In the above, properties for mobile(xs) size will also gets applied to tablet+ sizes in addition to some additional properties. What's the best way to write the above such that properties for mobiles does not get applied to tablet+ size?

Answer (score 0):

More than the `css` code, we need the markup fro your `html` where you're apply the class.
But for general rule, you can set multiple class for different sizes like:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    some content...
</div>
```

This will apply:

- `col-12` for `xs` size
- `col-6` for `sm` size
- `col-3` for `lg` size
- and so on...

more info on docs:

- [Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
- [Bootstrap grid example for mixing sizes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete)

Comment: my query is more about re-factoring css irrespective on how it will impact the html elements.

Comment: I see, then I do not understand your question well. Maybe you mean to apply `@media` `min-width` and `max-width` together to limit the class impact?

Comment: in the css, `.link` class has `margin: 7px auto;` which means it gets applied to element with `class=link` on `mobile, tablets, desktops etc` but if I do not want `margin:7px auto` on tablets+ devices then I will put `margin:0` in `@media(min-width: 768px){}` rule. What I'd like, is to re-factor the css such that I don't need to define `margin:0` to override `margin:7px auto`.

Comment: Still not sure if I get your idea... If I do, the only way I can figure to have two different conditions without override each other based on size _(that's what `media query's` are for...)_ Is to have two different classes, one for each.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you the full media query break-
You can use `min-width only or min and max-width together or max-width only`.

**example with all the three combinations**

```
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {

    }


@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

  }


 @media (max-width: 767px) {

 }


  @media (max-width: 480px) {

  }
```

Now bootstrap 3 uses the following break points for mobile first approach--

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px){

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px){

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px){

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px){

}
```